# Substitute those values greater than the 95% percentile with NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and I would like to substitute those values greater than the 95% percentile with NA.

So far I have tried the following:

```
df[ df == quantile(d$value, 0.95), ] <- NA
```

but I get the following error:

```
missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Testing equality in __`R`__ uses double equal signs, `==`. Additionally, it seems as though you have `NA` values in `d$value`, and the error message seems relatively straightforward and concise.

Comment: true, thanks for the hint. I will update the question

Comment: so basically `df[df > quantile(df$value, 0.95)] <- NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your data looks like:

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:7, value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

Then you may assign `NA` as follows:

```
df$value[df$value > quantile(df$value, 0.95)] <- NA
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Any ideas on how to go when there are NA in the original data.frame?

Comment: Just add na.rm=TRUE inside quantile() function like this: df$value[df$value > quantile(df$value, 0.95, na.rm = T)] <- NA

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use == to get a logical statement as bouncyball said. Note that you are now replacing all rows where df$value is equal to the 95th percentile, so you probably want to change that logical statement to

```
    df[ df$value > quantile(df$value, 0.95), 'value'] <- NA
```

Also specify the column that you want to change. The error message indicates that you already have NA's in your column. In order to exclude these to calculate the right quantile, set na.rm (na remove) equal to true in your function.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
quantile(..., na.rm=T)
```

to get rid of the error